# Retrieve the entire row with ResultSet of a CQL query

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I have set up a Cassandra connection through Java driver. And I want to retrieve an entire row as a collection. I want to get rid of using getString() or getInt() always. When I give a query saying select all columns in the users table using CQL. the entire result should be sent to a collection rather than a string. How do I achieve this?

I have done the following to retrieve the columns. It gives me the proper results. But I want to retrieve the entire row as a collection. 
Outside the for loop I want to retrieve these fields as one object. How do I do this??

```
String name=null;
String age=null;

ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM admin.users");
for (Row row : results) {
 name=row.getString("firstname");
age=row.getString("age");
System.out.println("name::"+name);
System.out.pintl("age::"+age);

}
```

Comment: since a row in cassandra may contain a huge number of columns (more than a million) it is not always a good idea to fetch all values) - so probably this use case is not supported directly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain all fields in a collection you could use [getMap(..)](http://www.datastax.com/doc-source/developer/java-apidocs/com/datastax/driver/core/Row.html#getMap(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)) function and you will get a Map with keys and values.

On the other hand, check new [object Mapping API](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/objectMappingApi.html) since version 2.1 and you can map a class directly from ResultSet with annotations in your entity class.